# How can I use an int as a HashMap key?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to use a `HashMap` to store instances of a simple class, called `User`. I'm using Integer as the key type, as I want to look up entries by user id, but I keep getting `NullPointerException` when I try to save a new entry.

Here's the snippet of code that's causing the problem:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(id);
User bob = new User(id, seq, packet.getPort(), packet.getAddress());
if (i == null || bob == null) {
    System.out.println("Null object.");
}
users.put(i, bob);
```

The values used in the User constructor have already been set, and the debug statement I added is never printed. Nevertheless, an exception is thrown when I try to call `users.put(i, bob);`. Is there another way to use an int as a key?

**Edit:** I'm dumb and didn't initialize the HashMap itself.

Comment: full stacktrace please also not that the `if` is useless. Also show us how you initialize `users`

Comment: I bet that users is null!

Comment: You're right, it was! And there was no stack trace other than `NullPointerException` on the line where I had `users.put(i, bob)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that users (your HashMap) is null

Comment: that's a wild guess :p

Comment: Well if the user were null, it would print "Null object," no? edit: I get it. And you're right.

Comment: Not user. The `users` collection.